# Get Steam Community Market price history with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, steam

I'm having trouble getting the price history of an item from Steam. By looking at other questions I've managed to learn a nifty way to construct a link which indeed gives me the price history of an item, my problem is that you have to be logged in to Steam to aquire this data. How do I view this data as if I'm logged in through an http-request? I've read other threads where they talked about browser sessions and how someone in my situation should set cookies of ones session-id but I haven't managed to get it to work in node. The status code I'm getting is 400.

This is my code:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  host: 'steamcommunity.com',
  path: '/market/pricehistory/?country=SE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=CS20%20Case',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Cookie': `steamLoginSecure=THE SESSION ID I GOT FROM WRITING
              "document.cookie" IN THE DEV CONSOLE`
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  console.log(res.headers);

  let body = '';

  res.on('data', data => {
    body += data;
  });

  res.on('end', () => console.log(body));
}).on('error', error => console.log(error));
req.end();
```

I'm not sure if there's anything wrong in my code or how to go about to solve this issue I'm having. I really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Steam has removed the 'steamLogin' cookie, thus explaining why so many people this past year have been encountering issues when using it in their code. Instead, you want to use the 'steamLoginSecure' cookie.

First you need be logged in to https://steamcommunity.com. Second you want to find the 'steamLoginSecure' cookie and copy what it contains. For chrome that would be:

Settings > Advanced > Privacy and security > Site Settings > Cookies and site data > See all cookies and site data > steamcommunity.com > steamLoginSecure

Now copy the content of 'steamLoginSecure' and have it as a cookie in your headers.

This is the final code I ended up with:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  host: 'steamcommunity.com',
  path: '/market/pricehistory/?country=SE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=CS20%20Case',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Cookie': 'steamLoginSecure=THE CONTENT OF "steamLoginSecure" HERE'
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  console.log(res.headers);

  let body = '';

  res.on('data', data => {
    body += data;
  });

  res.on('end', () => console.log(body));
}).on('error', error => console.log(error));
req.end();
```